# JQGrid do not hit the DB server when onSortCol or onPAging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that shows 50 rows out of 50000 every time the grid goes to the server it runs the method `public ActionResult CreateGrid(string sidx, string sord, string page, string rows, bool gridEvent....` this method always get the 50000 roes then shows just the 50 records corresponding to the current page.
I've added a static list where I maintain the 50000 records and I've added a gridEvent var on the UI to indicate if it is a gridEvent from onSortCol or onPAging or just a postback from submit button.

Code on the grid to modify the input gridEvent with the TRUE value when onPaging or onSortCol

```
 onPaging: function (pgButton) {
                $("#gridEvent").val("true");
            },
            onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder) {
                $("#gridEvent").val("true");
            },
```

Code to modify the input gridEvent with the FALSE value when hitting the submit button.

```
 function SubmitForm() {
    $("#getReport").validate()
    if($("#getReport").valid()) {
        $("#gridEvent").val("false");
        $("#getReport").submit()
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be right but when I look on the bool gridEvent on the Server method it is always false.  If I did not change gridEvent input type value on function SubmitForm() the value on the server always comes true.
How can I do to get the correct value, when I do a grid event or when I submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included the following declaration of the server Action in your question

```
public ActionResult CreateGrid(string sidx, string sord, string page, string rows,
                               bool gridEvent....
```

so you post the value `gridEvent` in some way, but you **don't included** the corresponding code. So I can only guess.

If you use for example just

```
postData: {
    gridEvent: $("#gridEvent").val()
}
```

it could be your problem because the `$("#gridEvent").val()` will be executed *once* at the grid initialization (creation). The correct usage could be

```
postData: {
    gridEvent: function() { return $("#gridEvent").val(); }
}
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for more information.

Comment: I've tried several things but I didn't try `postData: {
    gridEvent: function() { return $("#gridEvent").val(); }
}
` and this worked perfectly